# How to count memcpy in a C++ process

Tags: c++, count, memcpy

I have a process with multiple memcpy's getting called from different places. 
Is there any way to count how many memcpy command has been initiated during the execution ?

Comment: There are lots of ways that depend on your platform, your ability to modify the code, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool, I would suggest callgrind. Callgrind is a profiling tool that records the call history among functions in a program's run as a call-graph. Its a free tool in the valgrind suite.

Documentation can be found here:
[callgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.use)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing portable.  `memcpy` calls are often handled by the compiler, inlined for smaller types even if the `<cstring>` header that - directly or indirectly - declares `memcpy` says it's `extern` rather than `inline`.  Consequently, there may be no way to know whether some machine code was generated because of a `memcpy` in the source code.  You may or may not care.

***WARNING: ugly hack follows***

FWIW, if you can recompile the application and are just doing this for troubleshooting or interest - ***not for production use*** - you might try hacking it as follows and just seeing if it happens to hold together on your system:

```
#include <cstring>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, int> g_memcpy_calls;

namespace std
{
    inline void*
    instrumented_memcpy(void* dest, void* src, std::size_t count,
                        const char file[], int line)
    {
        ++g_memcpy_calls[std::make_pair(file, line)];
        return std::memcpy(dest, src, count);
    }
}

// may or may not need it at global scope too...    
inline void*
instrumented_memcpy(void* dest, void* src, std::size_t count,
                    const char file[], int line)
{
    return std::instrumented_memcpy(dest, src, count, file, line);
}

#define memcpy(DEST, SRC, COUNT) \
    instrumented_memcpy(DEST, SRC, COUNT, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    for (b = 'x'; b != 'z'; ++b)
        std::memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);
    std::memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);
    for (auto& where : g_memcpy_calls)
        std::cout << where.first.first << ':' << where.first.second
              << " called " << where.second << " times\n";
}
```

Note: in `g_memcpy_calls`, you might get away with using `const char*` instead of `std::string`, if your compiler ensures `__FILE__` returns a single `const char*` value for all uses inside any given source file, but that's just one more thing that might go wrong somewhere....